# How to refresh a component on each page change

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am calling a data service in an angular 2 component to load data on the `ngOnInit()` function. This component is placed on a Ionic tabs page. The `ngOnInit()` function is only called on initialization, but not on every navigation to the tab. I want to reload data from the data service on each navigation to the page, to refresh the component with the latest data.

How can I call a function in the component on each navigation to a tabs page?

This is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'reservation-list',
  templateUrl: 'build/components/reservation-list.component.html',
  bindings: [DataService, TimeService]
})
export class ReservationListComponent {
  public items: any = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    // this I want to call on each tab navigation!
    this.items = this.dataService.getEvents();
  }
}
```

My tabs are basically the ionic2-tabs example:

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root: any = Page1;
  tab2Root: any = Page2;
  tab3Root: any = Page3;
}
```

And the page is a basic ionic page where the component is insert:

```
<reservation-list></reservation-list>

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html',
  directives: [ReservationListComponent]
})
export class Page1 {

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a click event handler when you click your tabs and call that function.

In your tag

```
<a (click)="getEvents()"></a>
```

In you Component

```
getEvents() {
    this.items = this.dataService.getEvents();
}
```

Comment: Where should I place getEvents then? in the page? The page does not know anything about the component.

Comment: You should place in both. In your HTML template and in your Component.

Comment: If I do so, do I need to mark the items as input parameter? `<reservation-list [items]="items"></reservation-list>` ?

Comment: No, because you call the getEvents function inside the reservation-list component. So you don't need a items input

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the life cycle of ionic and use below method inside tab child pages.

```
ionViewWillEnter()
{
//apply your code
}
```

This method will call always when you come on page.